# SwitchCompat in BottomSheetDialog wrong theme color compared to sibling fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

[image: green colored SwitchCompat]

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the last SwitchCompat in my BottomSheetDialog is green instead of yellow (shown using the Layout Inspector).

The Layout Inspector says that the other two SwitchCompats that are yellow [that are in a fragment added to FrameLayout containerMultiFunctionButtonActions] don't have "style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog()".

[image: yellow colored SwitchCompat]

Why would that be messing up my SwitchCompat?

The correctly colored SwitchCompats are not overriding any style/theme, nor are any elements between them and the FrameLayout containerMultiFunctionButtonActions, so to me I think that I have clearly and successfully set up the style/theme.

Here is my layout:

```
...

<TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/groupMultiFunctionButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMultiFunctionButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/multi_function_button"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/app_primary_text"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerMultiFunctionButtonActions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:background="@color/pb_gray_light"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switchLost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:text="Why am I green?!?!?!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/pb_action_item_text"
        />
        <!--
        NOTE: textAppearance and textColor understandably have no effect on the switch color
        -->

</TableRow>

...
```

Anything else needed to debug this?
Should I really post my styles/themes?
They are all over the place, but they seem to be working fine everywhere else except inside of this BottomSheetDialog.

Comment: You say the other `SwitchCompat`s are "in a fragment added to FrameLayout containerMultiFunctionButtonActions"... when/where/how is this Fragment instantiated and added?

Comment: @BenP. Programmatically in onViewCreated via getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(containerViewId, actionAssignmentFragment, tag).commit() (not enough room here to paste all of the code)

Comment: Do the `SwitchCompat` instances in your other fragment have a style or theme applied to them?

Comment: @BenP. Confirmed no. Thus the mystery.

Comment: I think I have the answer, but to double-check... if you create a really simple style like this one and apply it to the misbehaving `SwitchCompat` using the `android:theme` attribute, does the switch color change to red? `<style name="redAccent"><item name="colorAccent">#f00</item></style>`

Comment: @BenP. Yes, that makes it red. Obvious now that I can use that trick to make my switch yellow, but I still won't understand why it wasn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found via the Layout Inspector, different themes are being applied to your switches.

The switches in the sibling fragment are just picking up your application's and your activity's theme(s), while the switch in the bottom sheet is additionally picking up the bottom sheet's theme.

The whole idea of themes is that they affect the attributes of all children, so any attribute used by `SwitchCompat` that is defined in `Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog` has the potential to "change" when your switch is inside a bottom sheet (compared to switches not inside a bottom sheet).

If you look at the source for this theme (and follow the chain of parent themes), you will eventually land on this:

```
<style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Platform.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_material_light</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Unfortunately for you, `colorAccent` is what defines the color of the switch when it's turned on, and the bottom sheet's theme is setting it.

You can solve this by changing the value of `colorAccent` for your `SwitchCompat`. You have a lot of choices of *how* to do this, but the simplest will be to create your own style resource and apply it to your switch using the `android:theme` attribute. Something like this:

```
<style name="YellowColorAccent">
    <item name="colorAccent">your yellow color here</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 20):

I agree with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596331/3713763) but easiest way to conform the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

with your theme is to set

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in the root element of your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`'s xml.